# How can i use promise returned data in another function later on

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

```
async function getOrderdata(orderId) {
  //await the response of the fetch call
  let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3245/api/Orders/' + orderId);

  //proceed once the first promise is resolved.
  let data = await response.json();

  //proceed only when the second promise is resolved
  return data;
}
```

I have the shown code and i want to use getOrderdata function in another js file?

Comment: Just use it in another `async` function: `let x = await GetOrderData(...);`

Comment: `const data = await getOrderdata(id)`

Comment: [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) that function from that file, and [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) into the file that needs it.

Comment: You can use this `async function` from another file in just exactly the same way you could use a normal `function` from another file.

Comment: Please show us the code of the other file, how you are trying to *call*  `getOrderdata`, and what went wrong.

Comment: In which environment are you working? Browsers, node.js, with a transpiler or not? How do you normally load multiple js files?

Comment: @Bergi I'm working with [fuse](https://fuseopen.com/)

Comment: @AhmedSalah Then please make yourself familiar with https://fuseopen.com/docs/fuse/reactive/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Put the function in a module.exports object and use an `async-await` function in the importing file.

```
// file exporting the function - exp.js
     module.exports = {
             getOrderdata : async function(orderId){
             //await the response of the fetch call
             let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3245/api/Orders/' + orderId);

             //proceed once the first promise is resolved.
             let data = await response.json();

             //proceed only when the second promise is resolved
             return data;
             }



// file importing the async function - imp.js
const { getOrderdata } = require("./exp.js")
;(async () =>{
    let msg = await getOrderdata()
    console.log(msg)
})();
```

Comment: `console.dir(Backend.getOrderdata('0294fa05-d535-4b58-88f8-12ae88404360').then((data) => {
 return data;
}))`

I use the above this code to print the returned data from getOrderdata and I'm getting `Object` 

Backend is the .js file where the fetch api exported.

Comment: @AhmedSalah try using `return JSON.stringify(data,2)` while returning the data .